# Existence of a Unif(0,1) random variable for counter-monotonicity

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

We know that for a pair of counter-monotonic random variables $X$ and $Y$, it holds that
\begin{equation}
(X,Y)\sim\big(q_X(U),q_Y(1-U)\big)
\end{equation}
for $U\sim\text{Unif}(0,1)$ and $q_X,q_Y$ being the quantile functions of $X$ and $Y$.
The question is, does there always exist a random variable $U\sim\text{Unif}(0,1)$ such that
\begin{equation}
(X,Y)=\big(q_X(U),q_Y(1-U)\big)\quad \text{almost surely}
\end{equation}
?

Comment: Why the first statement is true?

Comment: @Youem I think by the following: $\mathbb{P}(q_X(U)\leq a,q_Y(1-U)\leq b) = \mathbb{P}(U\leq F_X(a),1-U\leq F_Y(b)) = \mathbb{P}(1-F_Y(b)\leq U \leq F_X(a))= \max(0, F_X(a)+F_Y(b)-1) = W(F_X(a),F_Y(b))$ where $W$ is the counter-monotonicity copula